# HTML code in OOP PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, html, oop

I want to get some advice of using PHP OOP.

For example I'm createing some PHP/MySQL code using OOP and I need to output the code, how to do it?

I might have been bit confusing, I will show you all the code and you tell me if I do it right:

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once CLASSES."Pages.Class.php";
$obj = new Pages;

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $obj->setPage($_GET['page']);
    echo $obj->getPage();
} else {
    echo $obj->getFrontPage();
}

?>
```

**Pages.Class.php - one function from it**

```
public function getDatabasePage() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_seo_title = '$this->pageId' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="well">
                    <div class="page-head">
                        <?php echo $row["page_title"]; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="well">
                    <div class="page-content">
                        <?php echo $row["page_content"]; ?>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <?php
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}
```

***So basiclly the question is: Where do I need to put HTML code?***

In the *index.php* file or in the *pages.class.php* file?
How to do this right? Maybe I can get some links with documentation about this from you :) ..

Thanks.
btw - code is an example, not fully done. Just as example - I know it's not right as it is :D

Comment: read about MVC, you should separate logic from views

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/

Comment: OP, Care to check answer ?

Answer (score 1):

In your Pages class, create a separate method that outputs HTML and does only that; the DB-related logic should be in another method or (preferably) in a totally separate class.

```
class Pages {
   public function __construct(){
     //Object initialization logic comes here
   }

   public function getOutputHTML($resultOfQuery = ''){
   return "<div> Your html </div>";
  }
}
```

Other class file only for DB access , just pass parameter and get result as Database result.

```
class DB {
  public function insertMethod($table,$fields,$where){
    //Your logic
  }
  public function updateMethod($table,$fields,$where){
    //Your logic
  }
  public function deleteMethod($table,$fields,$where){
    //Your logic
  }      
  public function selectMethod($table,$fields,$where){
    //Your logic
  }      
}
```

Instantiate DB class like `$dbObj = new DB();`

Then you can access DB methods like `$resultQuery = $dbObj.selectMethod('users');`

So you can pass the $resultQuery result to other method like : `$objPages = new Pages();$objPages.getoutputHTML($resultOfQuery);` . It separates the Database and HTML logic/functionality.

I recommand you to use OOP with MVC so there will be templating system like Smarty,Blade etc.

Comment: I've expanded your explanation a little bit, hope you don't mind.